# Create Two Factor Authentication in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

Currently our webapps use Spring Security (Acegi Security 1.0.3) with username and password authentication. I have recently been given the task of plugging in two factor authentication (grid cards or tokens) into the framework.

However, there are many extension points in Spring Security - so I would appreciate it if you could give me some pointers as to whether I have gone about it in the right way.

The work flow would be: User logs in with their username and password > User is issued with a grid card challenge > Upon successful authentication they are granted access.

Here is the solution I have working at the moment.

1. Firstly I created a `SimpleFormController` (I called it `GridChallengeController`) that handles the two-factor authentication). If successful, users will be assigned the `GridUser` role and will be redirected to the page they originally requested.

**Code:**

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
AcegiCrowdUserDetails details = (AcegiCrowdUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
details.addAuthority("GridUser");
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken existing = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(), 
existing.getCredentials(), details.getAuthorities()));
SavedRequest saved = (SavedRequest) request.getSession().getAttribute(AbstractProcessingFilter.ACEGI_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY);
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(saved.getFullRequestUrl()));
```

2. Then I extend the `org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter` to allow for another authentication entry point. It will be triggered when the `accessDecisionManager` throws a `TwoFactorAccessDeniedException` (extends `org.acegisecurity.AuthenticationException`). Here are the relevant methods:

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint twoFactorAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    ...
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (TwoFactorAccessDeniedException ex) {
        handleException(request, response, chain, ex);
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        handleException(request, response, chain, ex);
    } catch (AccessDeniedException ex) {
        handleException(request, response, chain, ex);
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
    ...
    }
}

private void handleException(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, AcegiSecurityException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (exception instanceof TwoFactorAccessDeniedException) {
        sendStartTwoFactorAuthentication(request, response, chain, (AuthenticationException) exception);
    } else if (exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        sendStartAuthentication(request, response, chain, (AuthenticationException) exception);
    } else if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
    ...
    }
}

private void sendStartTwoFactorAuthentication(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, AuthenticationException reason) throws ServletException, IOException {
    twoFactorAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response, reason);
}
```

3. Finally, I extend `org.acegisecurity.vote.AffirmativeBased` to throw a `TwoFactorAccessDeniedException` when a user has not passed two-factor authentication (Users are allocated the `GridUser` role when they are authenticated with their grid card).

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, ConfigAttributeDefinition config) throws AccessDeniedException {
    super.decide(authentication, object, config);
    FilterInvocation f = (FilterInvocation) object;
    if (!hasRole(authentication, "GridUser") && !hasRole(authentication, "ROLE_ANONYMOUS") && !f.getRequestUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("/gridchallenge.htm")) {
        throw new TwoFactorAccessDeniedException("Need a grid logon");
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant snippets of my security XML file:

**Code:**

```
<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="authentication.TwoFactorExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <bean id="basicProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
            <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/acegilogin.jsp"/>
            <property name="forceHttps" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="twoFactorAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <bean id="gridProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
            <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/gridchallenge.htm"/>
            <property name="forceHttps" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler">
        <bean class="org.acegisecurity.ui.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
            <property name="errorPage" value="/accessDenied.jsp"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="filterInvocationInterceptor" class="org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager">
        <bean class="authentication.TwoFactorAffirmativeBased">
            <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false"/>
            <property name="decisionVoters">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
                    <bean class="org.acegisecurity.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="objectDefinitionSource">
        <value><![CDATA[
            CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
            PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
            /admin/**=Vaas_Administrator
            /guard/**=Guard
            /acegilogin.jsp=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /gridchallenge.htm=IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
            /**=VaasUser
        ]]></value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there any thing should I add furthermore so that my app to work correctly?

Comment: Reasonable looking solution here http://www.gobloomhealth.com/multi-factor-authentication-part-1/ . basically, log user in as normal. Strip their roles. Give them "requires more authentication" role, show two factor page, restore roles if validates

Comment: Out-of-date version of Spring/Acegi Security, consider upgrade.